# LibGDX / LWJGL start application maximized

Tags: java, libgdx

```
cfg.fullscreen=true;
```

makes it totally fullscreen.

```
cfg.width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
cfg.height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

makes it so the size is the screen size but it is still not maximized(I can hit the little box on the top right to make it snuggly locked into the screen. I just realized this was a nuisance after I launched my program several times and had to keep maximizing it.

Is there a simple way to... cfg.startMaximized=true?

Comment: This is on the desktop only, right?  You may be able to use an LWGJL API to set a window as 'maximized' .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274707/creating-a-maximized-lwjgl-window

Comment: @P.T. My project is for Android, Desktop, and HTML. Not worried about Android because it is automatically full screen and the HTML is no big deal right now. That link does not help, the code I posted already accomplishes that and LibGDX enables setResizable by default. I need the window to actually be maximized equal to when you hit the little box(I can click the little box manually but it is such a nuisance every time and should be done programmatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available nowadays:

```
cfg.setMaximized(true)
```

Comment: bonus points if you specify how to maximize across two monitors or select the single monitor to be maximized on!

Comment: I encountered a similar problem before, this should give you the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036275/libgdx-control-multiple-monitors