# LibGDX how to change screen to be maximized?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want my libGDX program to be fullscreen in windowed mode desktop application.

```
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration(); 
    new LwjglApplication(new test(), config);
    int h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    int w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    config.height = h;
    config.width = w;
```

makes it hang off of the screen and Display.setPosition is not doing anything. The screen is 1920x1080 but obviously I want this to dynamically detect it. I find it amazing people do not have a solution to do something like config.maximizeWindow();

Comment: [First hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029588/libgdx-lwjgl-start-application-maximized) via Google for "libgdx maximize window" leads to the same question asked by you a year ago. Is there a special reason for the desired behaviour?

Comment: @StefanHanke bingo, one year later and you still can't start a simple game or program maximized?! Why would you not want your program maximized?

Comment: You can submit a feature request on their Github site if there's no way to do it yet. Or do a pull request yourself.

Comment: @Tenfour04 request it for me will ya. How can you make a desktop application that doesn't have the ability to start maximized?!

Comment: Why would you want a game to be windowed and maximized?

Comment: @Tenfour04 because fullscreen is annoying, especially when you are using multiple monitors. It also allows me to quickly leave the game and come back into the game.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is cross-platform or not but the following works for me (Debian 10 Buster). When we set

```
config.height = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
config.width = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
```

Instead of just giving me a large minimized window, it gives me a maximized window.