# How can I set an OpenGL display (Window created by OpenGL) to maximized?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I would like to set my OpenGL display to maximised.

I can have users do it manually if I `setResizeable(true)` and then get players to click the maximise button, which [as a tester mentioned](http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-many-would-be-willing-to-help-me-test-privateers.26020/page-5#post-393465) is a pain and an unnecessary step for users.

I can set the display size to the same size as the players' screen, but that just looks odd, and I am not looking for fullscreen mode.

Obviously I can fullscreen and set display size already, but I am currently unable to find any method that actually allows me to actually maximise the display.

If you don't understand the difference between fullscreen and maximized ([Meta Stack Overflow discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276483/how-can-my-question-be-clearer)), then here is a description of [Maximized](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/maximize.htm), and here is a description of [Fullscreen](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/fullscre.htm).

Comment: What framework are you using to create a window and GL context? I suspect you might have to find the screen resolution and set the window position/size to match.

Comment: you can create the window with the maximize hint but that depends on how you make the window (and unrelated to openGL

Comment: @ratchetfreak I create the display by using 'Display.create()'. I have currently seen no way to give a "maximize hint".

Comment: @jozxyqk I can do that, but it is not the same, the borders look all wonky..

Comment: Its a bit unclear what exactly you want.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper What? I want to maximize an OpenGL display! I'm confused as to what is actually unclear.

Comment: Perhaps change the title to be about setting a lwjgl window specifically - it's the window manager and not GL which does the maximizing, but you have java and a lwjgl standing in the way. Maybe throw up a post on [their forum](http://www.lwjgl.org/forum/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent of the display to a `Canvas` attached to a `JFrame`, and then set that `JFrame` to be maximised.

Example:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setVisible(true);
try {
    Display.setParent(canvas);
    Display.create();
} catch (LWJGLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 4):

this is too long to be a comment, so i'll primarily post it here:

## Maximised Mode:

when calling CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx, use `WS_MAZIMIZE`.

```
 hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_MAZIMIZE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

[This thread](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/135611-Maximized-window-creation-using-OPENGL) may be of interest if you are using GLUT.

A suggestion [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/5) was to

> I think you can maximize the window by setting the Display location to
>   0px,0px and getting the desktop DisplayMode via
>   Display.getDesktopDisplayMode() and then setting this DisplayMode as
>   new DisplayMode.

## Full Screen Mode:

**setDisplayModeAndFullscreen**

```
public static void setDisplayModeAndFullscreen(DisplayMode mode)
                                        throws LWJGLException
```

- Set the mode of the context.
- If no context has been created through create(), the mode will apply when create() is called.
- If `mode.isFullscreenCapable()` is `true`, the context will become a fullscreen context and the display mode is switched to the mode given by `getDisplayMode()`.
- If `mode.isFullscreenCapable()` is `false`, the context will become a windowed context with the dimensions given in the mode returned by `getDisplayMode().` The native cursor position is also reset.

**Parameters:**

```
mode - The new display mode to set. Must be non-null.
Throws:
LWJGLException - If the mode switch fails.
```

Found [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setDisplayModeAndFullscreen%28org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode%29).

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596231/3436942) which *seems* to be filing an array list with possible screen modes - but I'm not certain

Comment: But I never call "CreateWindowEx"? Bit confusing.

Comment: Do you call 'CreateWindow'?

Comment: No. I call "Display.create()". That's it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the size of the LWJGL window using `Display.setDisplayModeAndFullscreen(DisplayMode mode)` as already mentioned by jbutler483.

But there is a trick to it. 
There are three ways to get these Display modes:

- '[new DisplayMode(width,height)](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/DisplayMode.html#DisplayMode(int,%20int))'
- '[Desktop.getDesktopDisplayMode()](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getDesktopDisplayMode())'
- '[Desktop.getAvailableDisplayModes()](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getAvailableDisplayModes())'

If you use the constructor you can tailor the mode to your liking, but these modes are all set to 'isFullscreenCapable() == false'.

If you want to go fullscreen you have to use 'getAvailableDisplayModes()'and pick one that has 'isFullscreenCapable() == true'. This is the only way to obtain a fullscreen mode.

And last but not least you can use 'getDesktopDisplayMode' to get a mode that fits the Desktop. I never tested if this can have fullscreen enabled.

Comment: Though this does not any way actually answer the question, getDesktopDisplayMode() appears to, as you say, return a mode that fits the desktop, which isn't quite fullscreen but is pretty close - So I gave it an upvote. Thanks for the help.